# Como comunicar dados do meu banco com gráfico(Highcharts)?

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Fala galera sou iniciante em php, estou tentando abastecer meu gráfico com as informações do meu banco.

[image: Esse é o erro que aparece pra mim]

[image: Meu código com a lógica de inserção de dados no gráfico]

[image: Banco para ajudar melhor no entendimento da pergunta]

Comment: Ai invés de postar a imagem do código você deve colocar em um bloco de código o exemplo. Assim fica fácil de ajudar.

Comment: @Allan Conde você está utilizando ajax? uma alternativa é enviar os dados para sua view(que terá o js construindo o gráfico) via ajax, ai no php vc ja deixa tudo formatado. Tenta dar um var_dump nos registros que estao sendo retornados no banco de dados pra ver se esta ok essa parte

Comment: @Allan Conde você tentou só o fetch ao inves do fetch_array?

Comment: @Karen Vicente tentei após seu comentário, porém não obtive resultado. Não estou utilizando o Ajax.

Comment: @AllanConde você tentou fetch_array() sem o parametro?, você tem esse código disponivel em algum lugar, tipo github acho que seria mais facil te ajudar assim? ou disponibiliza apenas essa classe grafico.php

Comment: @Karen Vicente Já tentei mas não deu certo, https://github.com/AllanConde/graficopesquisa.git

Comment: @Allan Conde obrigada!! eu vou tentar rodar o seu código para acharmos o problema :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz alguns ajustes no seu código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
  <?php

    include 'conexao.php';
    $resTotal = $con->query("SELECT * FROM aluno");
    $cnt = $resTotal->rowCount();

    $resProf1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM aluno where professor='lobato'");
    $cntProf1 = $resProf1->rowCount();
    $totalProf1 = $cntProf1 * 100 /$cnt;

    $resProf2= $con->query("SELECT * FROM aluno where professor='willys'");
    $cntProf2= $resProf2->rowCount();
    $totalProf2 = $cntProf2 * 100 /$cnt;


    $resProf3= $con->query("SELECT * FROM aluno where professor='allan'");
    $cntProf3 = $resProf3->rowCount();
    $totalProf3 = $cntProf3 * 100 /$cnt;

    while($filaProf1 = $resProf1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $prof1 = "{ name: '".$filaProf1['professor']."', y:".$totalProf1."},";
    }
    while($filaProf2 = $resProf2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $prof2 = "{ name: '".$filaProf2['professor']."', y:".$totalProf2."},";
    }
    while($filaProf3 = $resProf3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $prof3 = "{ name: '".$filaProf3['professor']."', y:".$totalProf3."},";
    }

    var_dump($prof1);
   ?>
<script src="highcharts/code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts/code/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



        <script type="text/javascript">

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
          <?php
            echo isset($prof1)? $prof1 : null;
            echo isset($prof2)? $prof2 : null;
            echo isset($prof3)? $prof3 : null;
          ?>
        ]
    }]
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alterei o `fetch_array` por `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` dei um var_dump do resultado e parece que esta ok.

Também alterei a linha:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
          <?
            echo
```

estava faltando o `<?php` e adicionei a seguinte validação:

```
<?php
            echo isset($prof1)? $prof1 : null;
            echo isset($prof2)? $prof2 : null;
            echo isset($prof3)? $prof3 : null;
          ?>
```

este ternário valida se a variável existe no escopo, pois se caso não encontre nenhum resultado para o `$prof2` ou `$prof1` ou `$prof3` a linha que estava pode ocasionar erro no php, tentando usar uma variável que não existe, pois ela esta declarada apenas dentro do while, ou seja apenas se achar algum resgistro na consulta.

Vi aqui que tem um erro de import do arquivo de gráficos, não sei se você esta usando arquivos da sua máquina, caso o problema persista envie o arquivos de imports também ai podemos te ajudar melhor.

Espero ter ajudado :)

obs: Considerei o seguinte banco:

```
CREATE TABLE `dbpesquisa`.`aluno` (
  `idaluno` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `sobrenome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `curso` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `professor` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idaluno`));
```

Comment: nossa perfeito, rodou limpo muito obrigado pela força Karen, agora vou conseguir incrementar mais dados e gerar mais relatórios em minha pesquisa.